# How debug a Hardhat task?

Tags: hardhat, debugging

I've developed a task in my Hardhat Project but I'm getting some errors when I try to pass an array parameter (something in @ethersproject/strings/src.ts/utf8.ts says that `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')`)

So I tried to debug this task with VS Code but I'm not successful so far. Using the following launch.json I've got the error: `HardhatError: HH5: HardhatContext is not created.`

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Debug Task: registerIssuer",
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}/packages/ntt/",
      "runtimeArgs": ["-r", "ts-node/register"],
      "args": ["${workspaceRoot}/packages/ntt/tasks/registerIssuer.ts"]
    },
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the verbose logging mode of hardhat. This mode will print a series of output that can be useful for debugging:

See: https://hardhat.org/hardhat-runner/docs/troubleshooting/verbose-logging